# How do i tokenise the non-space separated string?

Tags: tokenize, information-retrieval

if i have a string **"Hello,I am XYZ"** it can be tokenised into tokens :- **"Hello","I","am","XYZ"** . But How would i tokenise a non-space separated string . **for eg : "Hello,IamXYZ"** ?

Comment: Tokenize on what, English words? Read in a dictionary and see if any combinations match. But I expect a lot of strings will be ambiguous (two or more valid parsings)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have spaces in a string, then you use a dictionary to tokenize it.

Another approach is using ngrams, but be careful of the length of the string since it could create many ngrams!

Comment: How would i use dictionary ? I can use ngrams but it would be time consuming, i have to compare it with  ngram of every word present in my dictionary . for eg if it's WhereisIndia ?
its bigram would be {wh,he,er,re,ei,sI....}, I have to take {wh,he} and compare it with bigrams of all the words, then {wh,he,er} is compared with bigram of every word and so on....